# Can I implement an iterative training loop for the ELM classifier?

Tags: python, classification, metrics, training-data

I am using the Extreme Learning Machine classifier for hand gestures recognition but I still have 20% as accuracy.Can anyone help me to implement an iterative training loop to improve the accuracy?I am a beginner and Here the code I am using:I split the dataset that I prepared into train and test parts after normalization and I train it using the train function by calculating the Moore Penrose inverse and then predict the class of each gesture using the prediction function.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jul  4 17:52:25 2020

@author: lenovo
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'Sarra'

import numpy as np

class ELM(object):  

def __init__(self, inputSize, outputSize, hiddenSize):
    """
    Initialize weight and bias between input layer and hidden layer
    Parameters:
    inputSize: int
        The number of input layer dimensions or features in the training data
    outputSize: int
        The number of output layer dimensions
    hiddenSize: int
        The number of hidden layer dimensions        
    """    

    self.inputSize = inputSize
    self.outputSize = outputSize
    self.hiddenSize = hiddenSize       
    
    # Initialize random weight with range [-0.5, 0.5]
    self.weight = np.matrix(np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (self.hiddenSize, self.inputSize)))

    # Initialize random bias with range [0, 1]
    self.bias = np.matrix(np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, self.hiddenSize)))
    
    self.H = 0
    self.beta = 0

def sigmoid(self, x):
    """
    Sigmoid activation function
    
    Parameters:
    x: array-like or matrix
        The value that the activation output will look for
    Returns:      
        The results of activation using sigmoid function
    """
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1 * x))

def predict(self, X):
    """
    Predict the results of the training process using test data
    Parameters:
    X: array-like or matrix
        Test data that will be used to determine output using ELM
    Returns:
        Predicted results or outputs from test data
    """
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = self.sigmoid((X * self.weight.T) + self.bias) * self.beta

    return y

def train(self, X, y):
    """
    Extreme Learning Machine training process
    Parameters:
    X: array-like or matrix
        Training data that contains the value of each feature
    y: array-like or matrix
        Training data that contains the value of the target (class)
    Returns:
        The results of the training process   
    """

    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)        
    
    # Calculate hidden layer output matrix (Hinit)
    self.H = (X * self.weight.T) + self.bias

    # Sigmoid activation function
    self.H = self.sigmoid(self.H)

    # Calculate the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse matriks        
    H_moore_penrose = np.linalg.pinv(self.H.T * self.H) * self.H.T

    # Calculate the output weight matrix beta
    self.beta = H_moore_penrose * y

    return self.H * self.beta


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# read the dataset
database = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\lenovo\\tensorflow\\tensorflow1\\Numpy-ELM\\hand_gestures_database.csv")                  
#separate data from labels 
data = database.iloc[:, 1:].values.astype('float64')

#normalize data
#n_data = preprocessing.minmax_scale(data, feature_range=(0, 1), axis=0, copy=True)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data)
n_data = scaler.transform(data)
#identify the labels 
label = database.iloc[:, 0]
#encoding labels to transform each label to a value between 0 to number of labels-1
def prepare_targets(n):
    le =preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(n)
    label_enc = le.transform(n)
    return label_enc
label_enc = prepare_targets(label)
CLASSES = 10
#transform the value of each label to a  binary vector 
target = np.zeros([label_enc.shape[0], CLASSES])
for i in range(label_enc.shape[0]):
     target[i][label_enc[i]] = 1
target.view(type=np.matrix)
print("target",target)



# Create instance of ELM object with 10 hidden neuron
maxx=0
for u in range(10):
    elm = ELM(45, 10, 10)

    # Train test split 80:20
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(n_data, target, test_size=0.34, random_state=1)

    elm.train(X_train,y_train)

    y_pred = elm.predict(X_test)

    # Train data
    correct = 0

    total = y_pred.shape[0]
    for i in range(total):
        predicted = np.argmax(y_pred[i])
        test = np.argmax(y_test[i])
        correct = correct + (1 if predicted == test else 0)    
    print('Accuracy: {:f}'.format(correct/total))
    if(correct/total>maxx):
        maxx=correct/total
print(maxx)
###confusion matrix    
import seaborn as sns
y_pred=np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_true=(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1))

target_names=["G1","G2","G3","G4","G5","G6","G7","G8","G9","G10"]

cm=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
#cmn = cm.astype('float')/cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]*100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
sns.heatmap(cm/np.sum(cm), annot=True, fmt='.2f',xticklabels=target_names,      yticklabels=target_names, cmap='Blues')

#sns.heatmap(cmn, annot=True, fmt='.2%', xticklabels=target_names, yticklabels=target_names)
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylim(-0.5, len(target_names) + 0.5)
plt.show(block=False)
def perf_measure(y_actual, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
    if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==1:
       TP += 1
    if y_pred[i]==1 and y_actual[i]!=y_pred[i]:
       FP += 1
    if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==0:
       TN += 1
    if y_pred[i]==0 and y_actual[i]!=y_pred[i]:
       FN += 1

return(TP, FP, TN, FN)

TP, FP, TN, FN=perf_measure(y_true, y_pred)
print("precision",TP/(TP+FP))
print("sensivity",TP/(TP+FN))
print("specifity",TN/(TN+FP)) 
print("accuracy",(TP+TN)/(TN+FP+FN+TP))
```

Comment: Hi, extreme learning machines are just a relabeling of the perception algorithm and there is rarely a good reason for using them. See [this](https://www.facebook.com/yann.lecun/posts/10152872571572143) by Yann LeCun. I would suggest looking into other methods for classifying gestures instead.

Comment: I think that you have to train the network several times, each time save your weights and other obtained results, then select the best ones that give you the best accuracy. May be it depends on the random initial weights.

Answer (score 0):

To your question about whether you can implement an iterative training loop for an ELM:

No, you can not. An ELM consists of one random layer followed by an output layer. Because the first layer is fixed, this is essentially a linear model and we can find the optimal output weights by using the pseudo-inverse, as you pointed out.

However, since you already find the perfect solution for this model in one step, there is no direct way to iteratively improve this result.

I would, however, not advise using an extreme learning machine.
Besides the [controversy](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/34y2nk/the_elm_scandal_a_formal_complaint_launched/) about their origin, they are very limited in the functions they can learn.

There are other well-established approaches for gesture classification that are likely more useful to pursue.